# How to join these tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following tables:

```
   match

 id   |   rival_team
----------------------
|  1  |   chelsea fc
|  2  |   real madrid


   player

 ID   |   name    |   last_name  |
---------------------------------
|  1  |    John   |      Doe     |
|  2  |   Peter   |   Williams   |


   called_up_players  

 match_id   |   player_id  |  substitution_id  |    
---------------------------|-------------------|
|     1     |      1       |         1         |
|     1     |      2       |        NULL       |


   substitution

|     id    |   match_id   | substitute_player_id | replaced_player_id |
---------------------------|----------------------|--------------------|
|     1     |      1       |           1          |          2         |
```

I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT called_up_players.match_id, match.rival_team, player.name, 
           player.last_name, substitution.id
FROM called_up_players, substitution, player, match
WHERE called_up_players.substitution_id = substitution.substitute_player_id
         AND player.id = called_up_players.substitution_id;
```

and the following output:

```
match_id| rival_team |   name   | last_name | substitution_id
--------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------
      1 | chelsea fc |   John   |    Doe    |         1
      1 | real madrid|   John   |    Doe    |         1
(2 rows)
```

However, I want the output to be like

```
match_id| rival_team |   name   | last_name | substitution_id
--------+------------+----------+-----=-----+----------------
      1 | chelsea fc |   John   |    Doe    |         1
      2 | real madrid|   John   |    Doe    |        NULL
```

to display all matches where John Doe was called up to the roster. Regardless the player was involved in a substitution, I would like to have the columns for the name and substitution_id

I think I can achieve this using JOINS , but I don't know how to join tables so I can have something similar to the above output. I tried many statement I got errors.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Should `match_id` in your example be 1 for `real madrid`? I.e. `chelsea fc` are playing `real madrid` in match_id = 1.

Comment: errors like, "There is an entry for table ' ' but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query"... but I did not explicitly say it because I don't really know how joins work. I am expecting some guidance

Comment: hey @JohnD . No, the match_id is still 2 because **chelsea** and **real madrid** are not playing against each other. Let's say those teams play against the team I am 'studying'

Comment: Understood, but then why is "real madrid" appearing under `match_id` = 1? Also, do you want John Doe whether he was an original player in the match or he was a substitute for some other player later in the match? Your SQL suggests that you're only interested when he was a substitute for someone else.

Comment: yes you are right, "real madrid" should be under 'match_id = 2'. I already edited the text, thanks for that. So, what I really want is n rows to be displayed, where n is the number of matches. If John Doe was a substitute in that particular game I want his name and the substitution_id to be displayed. If he is not a substitute, keep showing the match_id and the rival_team, but NULL in the rest of the columns (name, last name and substitution_id)

Comment: Well, I think it would be an easier approach if I keep showing his name but substitution_id is NULL whenever he is not a substitute in that game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Learning2Code and his answer I understood a bit more about joins and finally, I came up with an answer to get the output I wanted.

Instead of using INNER JOIN, I use LEFT JOIN so that, all records are retrieved from the table on the left and if there is no data from the table on the right, the field is just empty

```
SELECT match_id, rival_team, name, last_name, substitution_id        
FROM match  
LEFT JOIN called_up_players ON called_up_players.match_id = match.id
LEFT JOIN player ON player.id = called_up_player.player_id
LEFT JOIN substitution ON called_up_players.substitution_id = substitution.substitution_id
WHERE player.name = 'John' AND player.last_name = 'Doe';
```

Output:

```
   partido_id | contrario  |  nombre    | apellido  | cambio_id
 -------------+------------+------------+-----------+------------
            1 | chelsea fc | John       | Doe       |         1
            2 | real madrid| John       | Doe       |
 (2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are joining to match without a join condition, so this becomes a cross join not an inner join.

This is one example of why a different join syntax is considered best practice:

```
FROM called_up_players  
INNER JOIN substitution ON called_up_players.substitution_id = substitution.substitute_player_id  
 INNER JOIN player ON player.id = called_up_players.substitution_id  
 INNER JOIN match ON ???
```

Comment: I think I understand. So, you suggest not to use the inner joins (those you use in your answer) because there are no join conditions on match table?

Comment: I am suggesting using inner joins, you just need a condition for the final join.

Comment: To me it seems like you need a team table.  Then perhaps your match table could have three columns, matchID, team1ID, team2ID.  If you had a team table, you could also tie players to their teams.